# Array Indexing with strings

Tags: javascript

```js
let a = [1,2,3,4];
a['name']='Tony';
```

Why is it not showing an error? As it's an array and arrays don't have indexing of strings. And still the length of the array is 4.

Comment: arrays are object. any not index like key is not shown, but exists.

Comment: Welcome to the world of javascript.

Comment: see the difference between array and typed arrays.

Comment: @NinaScholz is correct.
`typeof [1,2,3] === "object"; // true`.

Arrays are also a form of objects, with extra behavior. The organization of contents in arrays is slightly more structured than for general objects.

You can learn more about Javascript array on [Array MDN Page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)